# getSubmittedValue() is coming null jsf

Tags: jsf

I facing one problem in jsf, when i attached  to my , as shown below

```
<h:inputText id="" value="" binding="">
  <a4j:support 
        actionListener="Action_Class.validateUserName" 
        event="onblur" />
</h:inputText>
```

As shown in above, when i am tabbing out from  field, validateUserName has to call.it is calling,but when i am trying to get my submitted value as shown below, 
null is coming.

```
UIInput input = actionEvent.getParent();
String userName = input.getSubmittedValue();
```

username is coming as null.(The submitted value is coming only in IE browser, but in remaining browsers i am getting null as submitted value).
Kindly do needful.

Comment: You need to assign the value field to managed bean right.

Answer (score 4):

The action listener runs during invoke application phase. At that moment, the input component's submitted value as available by `UIInput#getSubmittedValue()` is only available if the input component itself has failed conversion or validation. During validations phase, if the input component has succeed the conversion and validation, then the submitted value will be cleared out and the component's (local) value will be set. This is available by `UIInput#getValue()`.

So, you should actually be using:

```
String userName = (String) input.getValue();
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, an action listener is the wrong tool to perform validation (at least, the action listener's class name hints that your concrete functional requirement is to validate the username). You should be using a normal validator for that. Get rid of the whole `actionListener` and register a `<h:inputText validator>` or `<f:validator>` instead the usual way. The submitted (and converted, if applicable) value is this way instantly available as 3rd argument of `validate()` method from the `Validator` interface.

E.g.

```
<h:inputText ... validator="usernameValidator">
   <a4j:support event="onblur" />
</h:inputText>
```

with something like

```
public class UsernameValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        String username = (String) value;
        // ...

        if (!valid) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Invalid username."));
        }
    }
}
```